# RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long

Tags: pytorch

When I run this code:

```
torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(torch.amax(predictions, 1), batch_acceptance)
```

With
`print(tensor([1, 1]))`, return `"torch.amax(predictions, 1)"`

and

`print(tensor([0.5105, 0.5130], grad_fn=<AmaxBackward0>))`
returns `"tensor([1, 1])"`

I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class
> probabilities, got Long

So, I tried

```
torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(torch.amax(predictions, 1)?float(), batch_acceptance)
```

But I get the exact same error:

```
RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long
```

Any idea ?

Thanks